# como puedo sumar unos datos

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo la siguiente duda.

estoy haciendo un sistema de reservaciones para hoteles en PHP.
en algunas fechas el precio incrementa y en otras disminuye, ahora bien eso lo he traido desde la DB pero quiero saber como hago para sumar los precios normales: $PriceSystemArray['price'] con los precios aumentados: $price['price']

Archivo php:

```
$nameroom = Data::RoomsViewModel("rooms");


  if($item['name'] == 'Habitación Doble C/D'){
  $PriceSystemArray = array('in' => $dateinstr,
                          'out' => $dateoutstr,
                          'price' => $item['price']);


  for($i=$PriceSystemArray['in']; $i<=$PriceSystemArray['out']; $i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))){
    $price = Data::PriceSearch("price_hdcd");
    $UNIX = strtotime($i);
    $STR = date("d-m-Y", $UNIX); 
      foreach ($price as $row => $priceout) {
        if ($STR >= $priceout['dateini'] && $STR <= $priceout['datefin'] ) {
          echo '
          <tr>
          <th scope="row">'.$STR.'</th>
          <td>'.$priceout['price'].'</td>
          <tr>'; 
        } else {
          echo '
          <tr>
          <th scope="row">'.$STR.'</td>
          <td>'.$PriceSystemArray['price'].'</td>
          <tr>';
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de los resultados que quieres obtener?

Comment: ok, el sistema detecta el rango de fecha, y va imprimiendo el precio de la habitacion, si alguna fecha introducida por el cliente entra en el rango de fecha de un aumento de precio, imprime dicho precio aumentado. y así hasta que llegue la fecha de salida del cliente, ahora bien estoy imprimiendo en una tabla fecha y precio, pero necesito que al final de todo eso me sume todos los precios obtenidos para dar un total.

Comment: Sigo sin entender precisamente qué cosas quieres sumar. **Fuera del bucle, al principio,** tú puedes declarar una variable, por ejemplo `$total=0`.  Luego, **dentro del bucle** le sumas a esa variable los valores que se irán acumulando, por ejemplo: `$total+=$PriceSystemArray['price'];` y **finalmente, fuera del bucle**,  muestras el valor de total en una nueva fila: `echo "<tr><td>$total</td></tr>;`

Comment: amigo, al hacer eso me imprime "45454545"; y quiero sumar esto:

Comment: Todos los valores que me devuelve: $PriceSystemArray['price'] y $priceout['price']

Comment: Entonces en la parte primera del `if` también le agregas a `$total` el valor, de esta forma: `$total+=$priceout['price'] ;`  De ese modo, en el bucle, irá acumulando los posibles valores en la variable `$total`.

Comment: estaba colocando la variable mas jeje, pero ahora me sale "4590345390", 45-90-345-390, y creo que es por que el total lo puse dentro del bucle jejeje al colocarlo afuera si me impreme 390, pero no es el total, el total seria 690, falta 300 de $priceout['price']

Comment: Te escribiré una respuesta para que veas cómo deberías ponerlo... un momento...

Comment: ya va hermano!! ya lo logre, error mio no me acorde de modificar algo que había cambiado! MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!

Comment: y había sumado mas no eran 690 eran 780 xD

Comment: Ahí he escrito una respuesta, por si puede servir a otros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te había dicho en comentarios.

Podrías crear un acumulador inicializado a `0`, fuera del bucle, e ir acumulando en él los distintos valores.

En este caso el acumulador se llamará `$total`.  En PHP, para acumular valores puedes usar el [operador de asignación `+=`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.assignment.php) del siguiente modo: `$total+=$valorASumar`, o sea, del lado izquierdo la variable que sirve de acumulador, y después del operador `+=` el valor que se sumará a lo que ya tiene el acumulador.

Luego, al salir del bucle, imprimes lo que se ha acumulado.

Por ejemplo:

```
  $total=0;
  foreach ($price as $row => $priceout) {
    if ($STR >= $priceout['dateini'] && $STR <= $priceout['datefin'] ) {
      $precio=$priceout['price']; 
      $total+=$precio;
      echo '
      <tr>
      <th scope="row">'.$STR.'</th>
      <td>'.$precio.'</td>
      <tr>'; 
    } else {
      $precioSistema=$PriceSystemArray['price'];
      $total+=$precioSistema;
      echo '
      <tr>
      <th scope="row">'.$STR.'</td>
      <td>'.$precioSistema.'</td>
      <tr>';
    }
  }
  echo "<tr><td>$total</td></tr>";
```